# PHP running as root on Apache2 running as daemon

Tags: users, php, apache-httpd

On one of my servers, Apache2 is running as daemon user:

```
[root@sbecby07 ~]# ps -ef | grep httpd
root      1114 29432  0 10:13 pts/2    00:00:00 grep httpd
root     29773     1  0 09:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
daemon   29774 29773  0 09:03 ?        00:00:01 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
daemon   29775 29773  0 09:03 ?        00:00:02 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
daemon   29795 29773  0 09:03 ?        00:00:03 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
daemon   29858 29773  0 09:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
```

However, when I view `phpinfo()` via a simple PHP file on the browser, it shows that PHP is running as root (with `/root` homedir and all):

[image: PHP Info]

How is this possible? How do I change the user PHP is running as to be the same as Apache2?

The other servers I am managing do not have this issue.

Comment: If this is an Internet facing server, I would deal as it as potentially compromised; it does not matter wether this was intentaional or not; it allows easy escalation of privileges and the potential to has been abused by now is too high

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It is a corporate intranet facing server only used for testing web application. The production servers (also facing corporate intranet) do not have this issue (i.e. both Apache2 and PHP run as daemon)

Comment: search for  mod_ruid2/RUidGid, suEXEC or suphp directives in your Apache configuration and/or vhosts. Or even a recursive grep for the string root in your apache configuration dir. come back to me if it works, as I have additional comments, that I will include in a proper answer.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro no result for mod_ruid2/RUidGid, suEXEC or suphp. For string "root" all occurrences are inside commented line. httpd.conf already has line `User daemon` and `Group daemon` so I don't think the issue is within Apache2. I'm suspecting the user is switched somehow somewhere within PHP execution but I don't know where to start.

Comment: php-fpm rings a bell?